Does Macrodroid search ALL embedded folders in a directory or only the master?
Does Macrodroid search ALL embedded folders in a directory or only the master?
I followed Reddy Lutonadio's instructions on Auto-delete certain file extensions on my phone?
My unwanted files were TXT files of the same name that tag along with downloads in my email downloads and NFO files.  Wrote the script subbing my parameters and nothing happened to the NFOs in nested folders.  Help Please.  Is there a setting or option I am missing?
My phone is NOT rooted.
